# Find the mistake in my conditional probability calculation

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, conditional-probability, bayes-theorem

A meeting has $12$ employees. Given that $8$ of the employees are women, find the probability that all the employees are women?

I just defined the two events $A : 8$ employees are female and $B :$ all employees are female.
Thus, we need $P(B|A)=\frac{P(A \cap B)}{P(A)}$.

Now, we know that $P(A \cap B) = P(B)$. So, $P(B)=\frac{1}{2^{12}}$ considering equal probability of male and females. Also, $P(A)={12 \choose 8} \frac{1}{2^{12}}$. On dividing the conditional probability comes out to be $\frac{1}{{12  \choose 8}}$ but it does not match with the answer to this question. Where am I going wrong? Anyone please help!

Comment: The problem cannot be solved without knowing the probability distribution for the meeting composition, which you haven't provided. Your choice of the  binomial distribution is unusual for this problem, since it assumes either that the meeting participants choose their gender at random, or that the meeting participants are selected randomly from an infinite pool. It is more usual to use a hypergeometric distribution when the pool is finite and fairly small.

Comment: This problem is apparently circulating somewhere, as it's been asked again [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/530559/a-meeting-has-12-employees-given-that-8-of-the-employees-are-female-what-is-th). The comments and answers there provide many further reasons why the problem is ill-formulated.

Answer (score 2):

Your calculation of $P(A)$ gives you the probability that exactly $8$ employees are female, not the probability that at least $8$ employees are female. To calculate this, take
$$
\left({12 \choose 8}+{12\choose 9}+...+{12 \choose 12}\right)2^{-12}.
$$

Comment: The sum comes out to be $\frac{794}{2^{12}}$. In that case the probability becomes $\frac{1}{794}$ which is far from the correct answer $\frac{2}{9}$

Comment: @IronMaiden42 I'm not sure why my approach is not giving the correct answer, but I am standing by it under the assumption that the probabilities of being a man or woman are even.

Comment: @IronMaiden42 What is the source of this 'correct answer'?

Answer (score 0):

The probability of a female employee is not the same as that of a male employee.

If the probability is $2/9$, then the probability of a female employee can be found by solving for $p$:

$$\frac 29=\frac{p^{12}}{\sum_{i=8}^{12}{12\choose i}p^i(1-p)^{12-i}}$$

Thus $p\approx.88153$